# When i check the searchResult data with console.log, so to occur err

Tags: reactjs, next.js, format, react-props

[image]

This is my Search code,

```
import Footer from "../components/footer/Footer";
import Header from "../components/header/Header";
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";
import { format } from "date-fns";

const Search = ({ searchResult }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(searchResult);

  const { location, startDate, endDate, noOfGuests } = router.query;

  const formattedStartDate = format(new Date(startDate), "dd MMMM yyyy");
  const formattedEndDate = format(new Date(endDate), "dd MMMM yyyy");
  const range = `${formattedStartDate} - ${formattedEndDate}`;

  return (
    <div>
      <Header placeholder={`${location} | ${range} | ${noOfGuests} guests`} />

      <main className="flex">
        <section className="flex-grow pt-14 px-6">
          <p className="text-sm">
            300+ Stays - {range} - for {noOfGuests} guests
          </p>
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold mt-2 mb-6">
            Stays in {location}
          </h1>

          <div className="hidden lg:inline-flex mb-5 space-x-3 text-gray-800 whitespace-nowrap">
            <p className="button">Cancellation Flexibility</p>
            <p className="button">Type of Place</p>
            <p className="button">Price</p>
            <p className="button">Rooms and Beds</p>
            <p className="button">More filters</p>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;

export async function getServerSiderProps() {
  const searchResult = await fetch("https://links.papareact.com/isz").then(
    (res) => res.json()
  );
  return {
    props: {
      searchResult,
    },
  };
}
```

THis is my Header code,

```
import Image from "next/image";
import {
  SearchIcon,
  GlobeAltIcon,
  MenuIcon,
  UserCircleIcon,
  UsersIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import { useState } from "react";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main style file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"; // theme css file
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-date-range";
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";

const Header = ({ placeholder }) => {
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
 
  const [noOfGuests, setNoOfGuests] = useState(1);
  const router = useRouter();


  const handleSelect = (ham) => {
    setStartDate(ham.selection.startDate);
    setEndDate(ham.selection.endDate);
  };

 
  const resetInput = () => {
    setSearchInput("");
  };

  
  const search = () => {
    router.push({
      pathname: "/search",
     
      query: {
        location: searchInput,
        startDate: startDate.toISOString(),
        endDate: endDate.toISOString(),
        noOfGuests,
      },
    });
  };

  const selectionRange = {
    startDate,
    endDate,
    key: "selection",
  };

  return (
   
    <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 grid grid-cols-3 bg-white shadow-md  p-5 md:px-10">
      {/* left */}
     
      <div
        onClick={() => router.push("/")}
        className="relative flex items-center h-10 cursor-pointer my-auto"
      >
        <Image
          src="/image/airbnb.svg"
          layout="fill"
          objectFit="contain"
          objectPosition="left"
        />
      </div>

      {/* middle - search */}
     
      <div className="flex md:border-2 rounded-full items-center py-2 md:shadow-sm">
     
        <input
          value={searchInput}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
          className="pl-5 bg-transparent outline-none flex-grow text-sm text-gray-600 placeholder-gray-400"
          type="text"
          placeholder={placeholder || "Start your search"}
        />
       
        <SearchIcon className=" hidden md:inline-flex h-8 bg-red-400 text-white rounded-full p-2 cursor-pointer md:mx-2" />
      </div>

      {/* right */}
   
      <div className="flex space-x-4 items-center justify-end text-gray-500">
        <p className="hidden md:inline cursor-pointer">Become a host</p>
        <GlobeAltIcon className="h-6" />

        <div className="flex items-center space-x-2 border-2 rounded-full cursor-pointer">
          <MenuIcon className="h-6" />
          <UserCircleIcon className="h-6" />
        </div>
      </div>

      {searchInput && (
        
        <div className="flex flex-col col-span-3 mx-auto mt-10">
          <DateRangePicker
            ranges={[selectionRange]}
            minDate={new Date()}
            rangeColors={["#FD5B61"]}
            onChange={handleSelect}
          />
          <div className="flex items-center border-b mb-4">
            <h2 className="text-2xl pl-2 flex-grow font-semibold">
              Number of Guests
            </h2>

            <UsersIcon className="h-5" />
           
            <input
              value={noOfGuests}
              onChange={(e) => setNoOfGuests(e.target.value)}
              min={1}
              className="w-12 pl-2 outline-none text-red-400"
              type="number"
            />
          </div>
    
          <div className="flex">
            <button onClick={resetInput} className="flex-grow text-gray-500">
              Cancle
            </button>
            <button onClick={search} className="flex-grow text-red-400">
              Search
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Just when i check the searchResult(through props) in seacrch.js,so occured this err

But, open instec and refresh, show that err => (GET http://localhost:3000/search?location=8&startDate=2021-11-25T15%3A00%3A00.000Z&endDate=2021-11-29T15%3A00%3A00.000Z&noOfGuests=1 500 (Internal Server Error))

I don't know what is the matter.. if you know, please help me

Answer (score 0):

unescape your input dates before passing it to the `format` function

https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-leftpad-3lhvf?file=/src/index.js

In your code

```
  const formattedStartDate = format(new Date(unescape(startDate)), "dd MMMM yyyy");
  const formattedEndDate = format(new Date(unescape(endDate)), "dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Comment: I followed your code, but i got this err.. Module parse failed: Identifier 'startDate' has already been declared (11:10) ㅠ_ㅠ i feel like crying...

Comment: This means you re-declared 'startDate" - perhaps you copy pasted my lines, the idea was for you to use it in your context, anyways see the updated lines.

I would suggest setting up an example in codesandbox that I or others can fork and show your code working.  Your original error is that you are passing unescaped data to the date function, if the update shows more errors post a running example on codesandbox.io or equivalent.